# Associations Help for newby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm trying to get back into Ruby on Rails but have a question that seemed simple.  My application is based on having golf tournaments where each tournament can have 1 or more rounds of golf.  Each round of golf is played on 1 course.

I created the following associations:

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rounds, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tournaments, :through => :rounds, dependent: :destroy
  has_attached_file :logo
end

class Tournament < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rounds, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :courses, through: :rounds, dependent: :destroy
end

class Round < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tournament
  has_one :course, dependent: :destroy
end
```

I can perform the following:

```
- tournament.rounds
- tournament.rounds[0] or tournament.rounds[1]
- course.tournaments
- course.rounds
```

I thought I should be able to do the following

```
- tournament.courses
```

Also, course[0].tournaments appears to return duplicate data as if there are two tournaments associated with the course because I have two rounds.

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Tournament id: 1, name: "December", start_date: "2016-12-20", end_date: "2016-12-20", comments: "", practice_round_comments: "", created_at: "2016-12-19 18:57:25", updated_at: "2016-12-19 18:57:25">, #<Tournament id: 1, name: "December", start_date: "2016-12-20", end_date: "2016-12-20", comments: "", practice_round_comments: "", created_at: "2016-12-19 18:57:25", updated_at: "2016-12-19 18:57:25">]
```

My migration look like this:

```
class CreateRounds < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :rounds do |t|
      t.belongs_to :tournament, index: true
      t.belongs_to :course, index: true
      t.datetime :start_time, :null => false
      t.datetime :checkin_time, :null => false
      t.datetime :entry_deadline, :null => false
      t.decimal :member_fee, :precision => 6, :scale => 2, :default => 65.00
      t.decimal :guest_fee, :precision => 6, :scale => 2, :default => 75.00
      t.boolean :scoring, :default => true
      t.boolean :lunch_included, :default => false
      t.text :comments, :null => true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateTournaments < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :tournaments do |t|
      t.string :name, :null => false
      t.date :start_date, :null => false
      t.date :end_date, :null => false
      t.text :comments, :null => true
      t.text :practice_round_comments, :null => true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateCourses < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :courses do |t|
      t.string :name, :limit => 30, :null => false
      t.string :address, :limit => 30, :null => false
      t.string :city, :limit => 30, :null => false
      t.string :state, :limit => 2, :null => false
      t.string :zip, :limit => 9, :null => false
      t.string :phone, :limit => 10, :null => false
      t.string :website, :limit => 100, :null => true
      t.attachment :logo

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your round specifies that tournament `has_one :course` and should be `belongs_to` to match your migration